# Powershell Script to write computer name and local printers to csv

Tags: powershell

I have searched and searched, but have had no luck finding what I am looking for.  I want a script that will write the name of the computer and the local, not networked computers to a csv file.

Example:

computer name  printer1 printer2

From my research the following command gives me some of the information I am looking for as far as the printer info I want:

Get-Printer | select name, type

I would like to append the output to a csv file, and not overwrite it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `Get-Printer -ComputerName pc-name | where { $_.Type -eq 'Local'} | select name, type, ComputerName | Export-Csv  -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path "d:\test\printers.csv"` Note the [`-Append` switch](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293957).